# Coupling engines together

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

Annoyingly, I once found a paper about this, but I cannot locate it after several hours. Hopefully someone can help.

Imagine I have a hot reservoir and a cold reservoir.  Rather than connecting these with one engine (I'm thinking of a Stirling engine), I instead connect it with more than one engine, where the 'cold plate' of engine $\, n\, $ is coupled to (or the same as) the 'hot plate' of engine $(n + 1)$.  How do I go about analyzing the overall work done by the combination of engines?

I'm trying to effectively see how such an arrangement of engines compares to a single engine,  but I'm getting stuck on the equivalent temperatures to calculate for each intermediate engine so that I can see what the overall effect is or if such an arrangement would even operate

Comment: If you've studied the operation of a single heat engine using two temperature reservoirs (hot and cold), then I think that the extension of that to multiple heat engines operating between reservoirs that are at intermediate temperatures between the "hot" and "cold" reservoirs should be pretty straightforward. Why don't you show us what you've done and what the specific problem is? A schematic diagram showing a multiple heat engine layout would be helpful.